# loading class from a directory

Tags: java, string, class, directory, classloader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [custom classLoader issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592021/custom-classloader-issue)

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592021/custom-classloader-issue) i've tried to ask a question, but noone answered. so i'll try to formulate my question in another way and without code. **How** to make my classLoader to load classes from a specified directory? directory is taken fom a string
thanks.

Comment: *"here i've tried to ask a question, but noone answered."*  That is a sign you need to improve your question (or that it is unsolvable).  Do not repost it!

Answer (score 1):

You can just use framework provided [`java.net.URLClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html). No need to write your own. It supports loading of classes from directories and JAR files.

> Any URL that ends with a '/' is assumed to refer to a directory.
>   Otherwise, the URL is assumed to refer to a JAR file which will be
>   opened as needed.

It also supports a parent class loader. If this class loader does not suite your requirements, perhaps you can specify in more detail what you need. And in any case, you can look at the source and derive your own class loader class based on that.

Comment: thanks! and as you can see from my link to previous question, i've tried to use `URLClassLoader`. i'll try once more, but i had exceptions while working with it. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592021/custom-classloader-issue) for more details

Comment: Well you should post the details of the NPE you are getting. And check if you are specifying URLs correctly.

Comment: NPE is thrown  by `Class cls = c.loadClass(className); ` line. i set path like: "E:/someExistingFolder/blahblahblah/DirectoryWithClass/" and after that as you can see, method analyses whether the path is set and tries to load className from the set path, but it doesn't. may be i've done something wrong?

Comment: I'm going to answer in your previous question. Since there is code there.